# How to set environment variables according to stage in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

The environment variables in the lambda handler has to be set via lambda handler according to the stage. The values for schema, endpoint are different for different stage. How can this be done via yml template. I am new to this, so don't know how this will be done.

```
Parameters:
   Stage: {Type: String, Default: ''}
Resources:
   LambdaHandler:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
   Properties:
       Environment:
          Variables:
          ......
          ......
```

How to continue further?

Comment: You can refer [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/4795997cfbb2dbb693123051c67f25861e6c16a3/community/services/Lambda/LambdaSample.yaml#L75) example from AWS labs.

Answer (score 2):

template.yaml:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod
    Type: String

Resources:
  myLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          stage: !Ref Environment
```

Your shell:

```bash
$ aws cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides Environment=dev
```

Say you want a variable conditional on the environment:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod
    Type: String

Mappings:
  Environments:
    dev:
      LogLevel: "DEBUG"
    prod:
      LogLevel: "ERROR"

Resources:
  myLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: !FindInMap [Environments, !Ref Environment, LogLevel]
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume it would be:

```yaml
Environment:
        Variables:
          your-key: !Ref Stage
```

Comment: Okay. Can we also declare parameters according to stagename and set the variables according to the stage?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) like below

```
MyNotCondition:
  !Not [!Equals [!Ref EnvironmentType, prod]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this article on how to use stage parameters and use mappings to setup environment variables
https://www.singlestoneconsulting.com/blog/cloudformation-mapping-and-conditionals-making-your-templates-more-universal/